# Cassandra: Delete all secondary index in a keyspace using CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql, secondary-indexes

I am creating a batch job to flush all the data available in my keyspace. When I use the command `DROP KEYSPACE <keyspace>`, tables and data are getting cleared while the secondary index created for each table is not dropped. Is there a way to delete all the indices available in a particular keyspace using CQL? Should I mention each index name available in the keyspave like

```
DROP INDEX <indexname>
```

Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: > tables and data are getting cleared while the secondary index created for each table is not dropped


That sound like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

To your question of how to delete a secondary index, the command is indeed [DROP INDEX](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/drop_index_r.html), as you mentioned.

To the question of whether secondary indexes are being deleted when they keyspace they belong to is dropped, as Mikhail mentioned that **should** be happening (i.e. DROP KEYSPACE should remove everything). If you have a case where it isn't, that could be a bug in Cassandra.